# Problems with bool variables within a if else comparator

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean

I am trying to make an upgrade system within my game. I am using 3 bool variables (for 3 different weapons). I am having trouble making an if else comparator that will look at which bool variables are true/false (which weapons you have and don't have), and take you to an appropriate combat scenario. The if else comparator does not work, regardless of what weapon you have. It automatically goes to the "else" part of the statement (where you go if you do not have a weapon). I have included a simplified version, with only 1 bool variable. Please help.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int choice;
    int choice2;
    bool weapon1 = false;
    
    start:
    printf("Where would you like to go? 1. Store  2. Arena: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if (choice == 1) {
        printf("You got weapon1 from the store \n");
        bool weapon1 = true;
        goto start;
    }
    else if (choice == 2) {
        printf("You went to the arena\n");
        if (weapon1) {
            printf("You won the battle because you had a weapon\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            printf("You lost the battle because you did not have a weapon\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change `bool weapon1 = true;` to just `weapon1 = true;` You are defining a new `weapon1` in the `choice == 1` scope... but you want the `weapon1` variable from the `main` scope

Comment: You redefine weapon1 in your if statement making it local to that code block, remove 'bool'

Answer (score 3):

Writing `bool weapon1 = true;` inside the braces associated with `if (choice == 1)` defines a new `weapon1` that is unrelated to the earlier `weapon1`.

Change it to `weapon1 = true;`, which assigns to the earlier `weapon1` without defining a new `weapon1`.

Turn on all or most warning messages in your compiler and pay attention to them.

Comment: UV for the most important part "Turn on all or most warning messages in your compiler".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you reinitialize the weapon boolean variable.
Correct code is this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int choice;
  int choice2;
  bool weapon1 = false;

  start:
    printf("Where would you like to go? 1. Store  2. Arena: ");
  scanf("%d", & choice);
  if (choice == 1) {
    printf("You got weapon1 from the store \n");
    weapon1 = true;
    goto start;
  } else if (choice == 2) {
    printf("You went to the arena\n");
    if (weapon1) {
      printf("You won the battle because you had a weapon\n");
      exit(0);
    } else {
      printf("You lost the battle because you did not have a weapon\n");
      exit(0);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The original code makes a new variable also called `weapon`, it does not reinitialize the earlier weapon

Answer (score 0):

Use of `goto` in C (with some exceptions ligoing to the end of the function) is considers a horrible practice

When you have defined the variable you shall not use its type at the beginning of the assignment as it new definition. Instead `bool weapon1 = true;` do `weapon1 = true;`

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int choice;
    int choice2;
    bool weapon1 = false;
    bool endgame = false;

    do
    {
        printf("Where would you like to go? 1. Store  2. Arena: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("You got weapon1 from the store \n");
                weapon1 = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (weapon1) printf("You won the battle because you had a weapon\n");
                else  printf("You lost the battle because you did not have a weapon\n");
                endgame = true;
                break;
            default: 
                break;                
        }
    }while(!endgame);
}
```